# How to remove soaleplus.exe from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have tried removing it from the extensions section in Chrome settings, but it reappears every time I reopen Chrome. My computer runs on Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 - Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified, I assume, you are using Windows OS. It is a [potential malware](http://www.herdprotect.com/soaleplus.exe-7408271456e22aba562c4da2d66edccfd19f532c.aspx). You have to uninstall the program explicitly from control panel and then restart chrome. It should work. If it doesn't work, then you might have to scan your system by some good anti-virus like `kaspersky` or `avast`.

Answer (score 0):

You should download Microsoft Security Essentials (or another similar anti-virus program) I've used MSE in the past and it works well (without noticeably slowing down your system) there are no up-sells with it either (like you'll get w McAfee or Norton antivirus).

Just go to Google, search Microsoft Security Essentials. Then download and install the latest version (for Windows 7 32-bit)

It's free and should get rid of this program (looks like Malware to me).

Here's a link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/security-essentials-all-versions

Comment: donwload the 32 bit version then: here's a link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/security-essentials-all-versions